# Open controller from app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to open a view controller from app delegate if a push notification is clicked with the code below

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if(application.applicationState==UIApplicationState.Inactive ){
            let sdViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StudentViewController") as! StudentViewController
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sdViewController)
            navController.setViewControllers([sdViewController], animated:true)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navController
       }

}
```

The controller opens, however the menu icon to reveal the navigation does not work. How can i make the menu icon reveal the side navigation.

Comment: What exactly isn't working here? Can you attach an image?

Comment: @Honey the code works fine, but using that code the menu icon in the controller those not work when opened

Comment: what is  library you use for menu ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
rootViewController.pushViewController(sdViewController, animated: true)
```